# Can i change a column data type in a MySQL database without loosing any datas?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, workbench

I would like to change the type of some columns from Varchar to Double without losing any of the data in the table. I'm working with MySQL and Workbench to manage the database.

I've done some test... and with a table full of Varchar, when I change the column type to Double, it works perfectly... The previous data seems to be converted automatically. Is it normal? Is it Workbench who is doing all the work or is this a MySQL thing?

Plus, I'm using JDBC with Java to push the data into the table and it still works when I use the PreparedStatement.setString() method even when I changed the column type to Double.

I thought I had to convert myself all the lines into an other table, but if it works like that it's just perfect.

Thanks for the enlightenment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL does the work for you when you use `ALTER TABLE` statement (which is what MySQL Workbench does).

See the official [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html):

> When you change a data type using `CHANGE` or `MODIFY`, MySQL tries to convert existing column values to the new type as well as possible.
>
> > *Warning*
> > This conversion may result in alteration of data. For example, if you shorten a string column, values may be truncated. To prevent the operation from succeeding if conversions to the new data type would result in loss of data, enable strict SQL mode before using `ALTER TABLE` (see Section 5.1.7, “Server SQL Modes”).

Of course, you need to have compatible types.

Answer (score 0):

In MYSQL you first copy column from which you want to change data type, with typecasting into new column and rename it as old one.If you change the data type it works perfectly but for viewing perspective.It is not a normal behavior, a well defined approach is that mentioned it above.